# SQL sorting order descending

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, cursor

I want to sort the data by the column `KEY_High`, how do I sort it in descending order?

```
String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_High, KEY_name};
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
                             columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_High);
```

Comment: sqlite sorting for android

Comment: You may accept Yuri's answer if it worked for you. That's how this community works.

Answer (score 1):

`KEY_High + " DESC"` should do it